# Select cell from column with row value

Tags: vba, excel

This simple problem has caused me some recent issues.  I have a range of cells which are columns that hold onto different types of information.  Using a row value (Integer not Range) which is previously determined I am looking to perform a check with the values within a single cell.

For example, I look through a list of names in column A.  If the name is found it holds onto the Row value.  Let's assume that the row is 10.  This row value will be used in checking the column values for this row (I.e. C10, J10, and K10).  How can I select a single cell and then compare the values within those cells?

Comment: `=INDEX(C:C,MATCH("name",A:A,0))` will get the value from column C change the C:C to J:J and K:K to get them

Comment: How would I do that since I am coding in VBA using visual basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the equivalent to *MATCH() / INDEX()* or *VLOOKUP()* in **VBA** for getting the data for Darth Vader here:

[image]

we could use something like:

```
Sub GetTheRowValue()
   Dim RowValue As Long

   RowValue = Range("A:A").Find(What:="Darth Vader", After:=Range("A1")).Row
   MsgBox Range("B" & RowValue).Value
End Sub
```

The finds the proper row and then acquires data from other columns in that row.